# Should index include a 'constant' column?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, partitioning

I am doing partitioning in my postgres db. The root table is like kpis_weekly(date, personid, metric, value) and the partition table is kpis_weekly_yyyymmdd inherits from kpis_weekly table.
I set the primary key of the child table to be (personid, metric), as the date is always the same in the same partition table.

Is it the right practice? Or I should create primary key on (date, personid, metric), although the date is 'constant' inside the same partition table.

The queries that we normally run on this table are like:

```
select * 
from kpis_weekly  
where date = '2011-02-20' 
and personid = 50

select * 
from kpis_weekly  
where date = '2011-02-20' 
and metric = 'centrality' 
and personid in ( 50, 82, 10, 14, 22, 36)
```

Comment: Very good question. I haven't explored the impact of adding a 3rd column to a b-tree index where that column is a single constant value.

Answer (score 0):

If the pair personid - metric is unique then yes, it's better to have a primary key based on these two columns. In any case the primary key of the master table cannot be propagated to the child tables, so including date to the key is useless.

Comment: when creating an index. consider having the first element of the index the column with less diverse values. If I understood correctly, it should be metric, then personid then